# Save pandas dataframe to hdf

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am using the inbuilt pandas function of saving to a hdf:

```
df_bagg.to_hdf('bagg_data.hdf','bagg',mode='w').
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tables' has no attribute 'misc'
```

Comment: may be this `misc` is missing. I cannot reproduce in my side.

Comment: Try updating PyTables.